# Split View Controller's detail view off-center because of master view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is a weird quirk. I'm working with a `UISplitViewController`, and I have a `UILabel` positionally set up like this within my detail view controller:

```
self.label.center = self.view.center;
```

It works, but the weird component is that the center it is set to is not accurate. If the Master controller were not on there, it would be the center of a view taking up the whole screen. Instead, it is offset to the right. I think that my view thinks it is larger than it really is, which makes centering the `UILabel` weird.

Why am I getting this result, though? Other subviews are fine in terms of width when loaded into this paradigm...

Comment: do `label` and `view` have same parent view?

Comment: `view` is the parent view, label is a child of that view. There are other children to the view that center adjust to width as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting one center to another center like that only works if the two views are siblings, but in your case one is contained within the other.  Try this instead:

```
self.label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.height / 2);
```

Comment: By the way, your approach (setting the child's center to the parent's center) would probably work just fine if the parent view had an origin of 0,0.  If the parent view is within another view and not at the top left corner, then it won't work.